# Sql Server Recursive Cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

If I create a Cursor for, for example, `SELECT id FROM myTable`, and while iterating over it, I insert into myTable, does the cursor will get this new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can just try and see... It does until you've declared your cursor as `static`.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) for reference:

> STATIC 
>   
>   Defines a cursor that makes a temporary copy of the data to be
>   used by the cursor. All requests to the cursor are answered from this
>   temporary table in tempdb; therefore, modifications made to base
>   tables are not reflected in the data returned by fetches made to this
>   cursor, and this cursor does not allow modifications.

Comment: its the only explanation i can came up for the behavior i'm observing... :( i just wanted to be sure...

Comment: you are 100% correct! static solved my problem!